# Spring Data Rest: how to intercept events on a "shared" Repository?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

Imagine this scenario.

I have two Spring Data Rest applications that "share" some entities, but with different @Repository (every app has his @Repository for the same entity).

Example:

```
Application1
    - PersonRepository<Person>
Application2
    - PersonRepository<Person>
```

Application1 makes some operations on PersonRepository (save or modify).

If I use AbstractRepositoryEventListener I can easiliy intercept every operation made on THAT repository (only for Application1).

But how to intercept that events on Application2?
It's possibile with Spring Data Rest?

Any idea will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I will keep my event listener in the service layer. So that the event listener works for any application with PersonRepository module included. May be in the property file of each application i specify an environment variable to identify which application the event has been triggered.

Comment: I do not believe it is possible with just event listeners. I'm assuming that when you say two applications, it means two processes with their own JVM. In this case, I think the two applications have to be able to inform each other of their events.

Comment: Yes, is a valid idea. But in this way the management of the repositories will be external from the applications, and each application will need to link to an external service. I can't do this for my task.

Comment: @Chris: exactly, every application has his own JVM. I'm looking to investigate if there is a way to inspect what happens in the @ Entities mapped by a @ Repository (just an example: an external application makes an insert on the database, I want to understand if there is a way to "view" that change on the database.

Comment: It may be possible to do some of it with auditing. Take a look at the http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#auditing

Comment: Thanks Chris. I tried the auditing approach, creating a Listener with the @ EntityListers annotation. I tried to make a @ PostPersist, but only the application who make the operation with the entity is "aware" of the change on the repository; the other application is not aware of that persistence.